# Objective-C Garbage Collection - What does it do?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Being a python programmer for four years now (it doesn't mean much though) and moving to Objective-C the one concept that is weird and "alien" to me is memory management. Luckily garbage collectiom exists and I only intend to develop apps for the mac OS 10.6+, so in all my projects so far I have always turned garbage collection to required. But here is my problem: when I use Instruments with the Alloc and Leaks tool I see leaked bytes poppin in the graph. ??? Very weird. What does Garbage Collection really do, when it is required. The way I see it is that you can completely forget about retain, release, etc. But is that true? Please provide examples where GC will help and where it won't (if any), so that I can understand what I am doing wrong.

### Edit

I probably should have been more clear. The problem I want to solve is the fact that, even after GC is set up as required, Instruments still finds leaks. I also asked what GC does just so I could make sure that it does what I think, and the problem is not in my code or in GC, but elsewhere. That "elsewhere" is what I want to find out.

Comment: Have you read the official documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/GarbageCollection/Introduction.html  ? Which info **in addition to the official doc** do you want?

Comment: Well, in addition to clarifying what GC does, I'd also like some pointer to a reason why, even after GC is required, Instruments still sees leaks in my code.

Comment: Which object is leaked? Did you use any CoreFoundation functions like `CF...Create...` ?

Comment: We can't answer questions about why your code displays leaks unless you post the code, and as @Yuji implied in the first comment, this is otherwise an overly-broad and vague question. Please post another question asking about your code and try to edit this one to address a specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have time to wait for the next version of Xcode to be released (together with Lion), you can directly move to [ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1164724).

ARC will - in the intermediate run - replace GC in OS X and iOS.

If you are a registered Apple Developer, you can check out presentations on ARC in the WWDC2011 videos.

Comment: Well, I have Xcode 4, but I'm using 10.6. I don't think I have that. In the meantime, what does ARC do, exactly? Is it really "all the advatages of garbage collection without the overheads"? I have edited my question, please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer your question is, when you have variables or objects that are allocated to memory, GC cleans up the mess for you.  Whereas; in iPhone and iPad applications, you must clean it up yourself because GC doesn't exist.

Example:

```
NSArray* arr = [[NSArray alloc] init]; // Allocated to memory
[arr release]; // released from memory
```

Comment: That is what I thought, but still there are leaks in my code somehow. Please see my question again, I've updated it.

Comment: Hi you need to tell us which objects Instruments reports to be leaked. Could you upload Instruments report, for example? We are not psychics who can read into your code!

Comment: @Yuji Well, you're totally right! Me neither, by the way :) [Here](http://www.esb.ucp.pt/twt/WebDiskOGM/MyFiles/Alex/Report_Trace.zip) is the download url. Please just look at the first run. The second is nothing. Thanks very much! PS: If you find too much CF/NSString in there: the profiled app analyzes strings given by the user.